# boundary of the support of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a non-negative continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A=\{x:f(x)>0\}$.

Is it true that the Lebesgue measure of $\partial A$ is $0$?

I can't prove it or find a counter example for it.

Any comment is greatly appreciated!

Comment: False, since $\partial A$ can be a Cantor type set (define $f$ separately on each component of $A^c$), and these can have positive measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick any closed set $B$ with empty interior in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider $f(x) = d(x, B)$.

Note that $f$ is continuous, nonnegative and $A = \{ f>0\} = \mathbb R^n \setminus B$.

Now let $x\in \partial A$, then first of all $f(x) = 0$ and so $x\in B$. If $x\in B$, then as $B$ has empty interior, there is a sequence $y_n \notin B$ so that $y_n \to x$. This shows $B \subset \partial A$. Thus $B = \partial A$.

But in general, a closed set with empty interior might have positive measure.

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice example!